# Assert.DoesNotThrow with NUnit -- how to get stack trace?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, testdriven.net

I am using NUnit for unit testing (running with TD.NET).

When using Assert.DoesNotThrow, i get the exception, but without any stack trace, which makes it harder to identify root issue.

How can i tackle this?

Comment: Just for info:  Both Resharper unit test and Visual Studio unit test (using VSTest and the NUNit3Adapter) show full stack trace for the DoesNotThrow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Assert.DoesNotThrow` is redundant, if a tests throws the test will fail automatically *without* an assert. To clarify what is being tested is, in my humble opinion, better conveyed in the test method name. There is very little documentation benefit in the `Assert.DoesNotThrow` syntax and, as you point out, just makes it harder to fix failing tests.

Also, if you have a very long test with multiple asserts the `Assert.DoesNotThrow` fills an important role as to assert that the correct code block threw an exception. However, in this case a more suitable solution is to see if the test can be shortened and/or asserts moved into their own tests.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it really answers your question, but I'd shorten the test to a single situation so that you don't need to wrap some code into a delegate that you pass to `Assert.DoesNotThrow`. Then, just write the test without any assertions. A test that throws an unexpected exception will fail, so it will do what you want, and you'll get the full exception.

About 10%-ish of my tests work like this; no assertions at all, and method names like `ThisOrThatShouldNeverThrow()`.

Another option, while debugging, is to run the test in a debugger (using TD.Net) and in Debug|Exceptions check some additional boxes so that the debugger stops when the exception is thrown.

Comment: There are many other ways to accomplish this, but i was wondering about the DoesNotThrow method, and more specifically, if NUnit can be configured to display this information. I can mimic the DoesNotThrow method (which simply wraps a try..catch i assume) and output this information myself.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were trying to solve a practical problem. In this case, why not patch it in NUnit and contribute it? Fair chance you're not the only person interested in this feature.